# Not able to access a rest service in Microsoft Azure VM

Tags: rest, azure, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04

I am having problem to access a node js rest service deployed on an ubuntu virtual machine. I am able to access the VM using putty, however I am not able to ping the reserve ip from command line. I have put the logs in the rest service as when it gets the hit it prints the log, the logs are not getting printed. I want to know if there is any additional setting which needs to be done to open a port from the virtual machine or it is supposed to be open by default. If I need to open the port in order to access the service, where should I look for it.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Is Azure VM a classic VM ?

Comment: I guess so, how do I check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if there is any additional setting which needs to be
>   done to open a port from the virtual machine or it is supposed to be
>   open by default.

No, Azure will not open other ports by default, we should open ports manually.

> I am not able to ping the reserve ip from command line

It is a **classic** VM, am I right? if so, we should make sure the rest service listening on which port, and add endpoints via Azure portal:
[image]

More information about create an endpoint please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/setup-endpoints).

If your VM in **ARM module**, we should add a inbound rules to NSG.

[image]

More information about NSG, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal).